# Openbravo.log: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Tags: java, tomcat, out-of-memory, openbravo

I "ant install.source" Openbravo, then "ant war", put .war to the /opt/tomcat/webapps, restated tomcat service. "catalina.out" says:

```
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/examples
org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [9,302] milliseconds.
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/examples has finished in 10,126 ms
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/openbravo
org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Exception in thread "main"
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
```

and nothing more, openbravo.out says this:

```
**Initializing in-memory model...
org.openbravo.base.model.ModelProvider - Building runtime model
org.openbravo.dal.core.DalLayerInitializer - Model read in-memory, generating mapping...
ERROR org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.BasicLazyInitializer - Javassist Enhancement failed: org.openbravo.model.common.order.Order
java.lang.RuntimeException: by java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space**
```

Here are my CATALINA_OPTS in /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service

```
CATALINA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/ -Xms384M -Xmx1536M -server -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRGridLayout,horizontallyMergeEmptyCells"
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: Please provide a closer description of what you're trying to do and what's not working

Comment: I'm trying to deploy Openbravo system. After war-file was deployd, i restart tomcat and see this errors

Comment: @TMob I'm trying to deploy Openbravo system. After war-file was deployd, i restart tomcat and see this errors

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
Just start using java 1.8 instead 1.7